# dragAndDrop in selenium javascript

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

```
dragAndDrop()
```

**How to do dragAndDrop in *selenium* with javascript?**

> element drag and drop sorting

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you.

```
let actions = driver.actions({async: true, bridge:true});
await driver.findElements(By.css('.box2'))
.then(async(firstBoxes) => {
    for (firstBox of firstBoxes) {
        await actions.move({async: true, origin:firstBox}).press().perform();
        await driver.findElements(By.css('.box1'))
        .then(async(boxes) => {
            for (secbox of boxes) {
                await actions.dragAndDrop(firstBox, secbox).release().perform();
            }
        });
    }
});
```